# Identify the purchased medicine about to expire

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

My English is bad and I don't know all the necessary terms to ask properly so I'm really sorry. I need help about an MS Access query.

I'm creating a BD for a medicine store and I need a list of the medicine which is purchased but not yet sold and will be expired within one week. Recording the 'purchase lot number' is not possible because it's a busy store and it is not much necessary.

So it should be like:

```
PURCHASE:
S.   Medicine   ExpDate   Amount
1.   M1          7/1/19       50
2.   M1          9/1/19       50
2.   M2          9/1/19      100
3.   M1         15/1/19      100

TOTAL SOLD AMOUNT:
Medicine  1/1/19   5/1/19   9/1/19
M1            30       30       20
M2            50       30       10
```

So if I run the query on the 1st of the month the result would be:

```
M1   20
```

and if I run the query on the 10th the result would be:

```
M1  120
M2   10
```

Please ask if it's needed to know anything more.

Do anyone know how can I create this query? or how can I do it? or any other post about such topic?

Comment: Record the sales in a table like that purchase with a record for each product and date, and a simple query can be used.

Comment: How is your sales table designed (don't say "I just have it in Excel")? How do you know that the M1 sold on 1/1/19 (which is a future date) wasn't from the group with an expiration date of 9/1/19?

Comment: @ImtiazSiddique . . . Without the purchase lot number, you don't know which lot was sold.  Hence, you don't have the data to answer your question.  You first need to collect the right data because you can run queries to get the information you want.